# good way to redirect url in a django app

Tags: python, django

I'm constructing a Django app where I have a main page that links to different URLs to perform actions (for example there's a link to add a record to the database).  This is done using forms in the templates and changes the current URL from app/index to app/add.  The problem is that when I use render_to_response in the script that manages that action it doesn't change the URL but it does change the html being used back to the index page.  So this works if you use the links in the app but if the user at any point tries to refresh one of those pages it might perform the action again (ie if you refresh app/add it'll add that record again).  I would use HttpResponseRedirect or redirect, but I need to pass a context that includes a jobList (see below wherever I use render_to_response). My current fix is to lump all of the action into the index page's script and have all of action buttons redirect to it with options submitted but this is a terrible way to structure a program I feel and surely there has to be a better way to do this.  Hope this isn't too much text. For reference, here's a couple of the relevant files.  Thanks in advance for any help.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from Minion.models import Job

urlpatterns = patterns('Minion.views',
    # URLs for the MinionUI app
    url(r'^$', 'home'),
    url(r'^index/$', 'detail'),
    url(r'^add/$', 'add'),
    url(r'^output/$', 'output'),
    url(r'^change/$', 'change'),
    url(r'^cal/$', 'calendarTest'),
    url(r'^delete/$', 'delete'),
    url(r'^change/$', 'change'),
)
```

views.py (only parts of it, don't want to clutter the screen too much)

```
#This script is responsible for whatever operations need to happen before viewing the index page again and then displaying the index page
#This includes:
#user authentication
#adding entries to the database
def detail(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if 'isAdding' in request.POST:
            #Add data to database
            job = Job()
            job.name = request.POST['name']
            job.user = request.POST['user']
            job.command = request.POST['command']
            job.ipRange = request.POST['ipRange']
            job.whenToRun = str(request.POST['dateToRun']) + ' ' + str(request.POST['timeToRun'])
            job.save()
        elif 'isChanging' in request.POST:
            #Change selected data in database
            job = Job()
            job.name = request.POST['name']
            job.user = request.POST['user']
            job.command = request.POST['command']
            job.ipRange = request.POST['ipRange']
            job.whenToRun = str(request.POST['dateToRun']) + ' ' + str(request.POST['timeToRun'])
            job.save()
        jobList = Job.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('Minion/detail.html', {'jobList': jobList}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else: #need to authenticate user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    jobList = Job.objects.all()
                    return render_to_response('Minion/detail.html', {'jobList': jobList}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                else:
                    return render_to_response('Minion/home.html', {'loginFail': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                return render_to_response('Minion/home.html', {'loginFail': True})
        else:
            return render_to_response('Minion/home.html', {'improperURL': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

detail.html(main index template)

```
{% load i18n %}
<head>
    <!script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //These two function are used to change where we direct our POST data to
        function determineWhereToGo(){
            try{
                var element = document.getElementById('dropdown');
                var selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
                if(selected === "Delete"){
                    document.getElementById('checkboxes').action = "{% url 'Minion.views.delete' %}";
                }else if(selected === "Change"){
                    document.getElementById('checkboxes').action = "{% url 'Minion.views.change' %}";
                }
            }catch(err){
                alert("Javascript Error\n" + err.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th />
        <th>Job ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Command</th>
        <th>IP Range</th>
        <th>Date to Run</th>
    </tr>
    <form id="checkboxes" method="post" action="{%url 'Minion.views.detail' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for job in jobList %}
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ job.id }}Selection"/></td>
                <td>{{ job.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.user }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.command }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.ipRange }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.whenToRun }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <select id="dropdown" onchange="determineWhereToGo();">
            <option />
            <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
            <option value="Change">Change</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'Minion.views.add' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</table>
```

add.html (this is a template with the use of the isAdding option selected for reference)

```
{% load i18n %}

<h1>Add a Job</h1>
<hr width="18%" size="3" align="left" />
<form method="post" action="{% url 'Minion.views.detail' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    Name<input type="text" name="name" /><br /><br />
    User<input type="text" name="user" /><br /><br />
    Command<input type="text" name="command" /><br /><br />
    IP Range<input type="text" name="ipRange" /><br /><br />
    Date to Run<input type="date" name="dateToRun" value="YYYY-MM-DD" /><br /><br />
    Time to Run<input type="time" name="timeToRun" value="HH:MM:SS" /><br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="isAdding" value="True" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Job" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should add detail in your question that you want to pass context data along with redirect.

Comment: Have you considered using a middleware to do the redirection for you based on the context variable ?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that option, do you know of a good guide on how to accomplish this sort of thing or can you give some instruction?  The tutorial on docs.django.com didn't really make clear to me how I can specify this property of allowing me to redirect to the detail.html in such a way that that template knows what data to display.

Comment: Why not to get this jobList again in a view you redirected to after a 'form' action and pass it to it's template? - For your detail: 'I would use HttpResponseRedirect or redirect, but I need to pass a context that includes a jobList...'. If you redirect then you can not to request the list in a view from which you redirect but do it in a final view.

Comment: @sergzach because I need a way for my template to be displaying that data, that restraint is the only thing really keeping me from just using redirect.  Whether or not the detail view is the one responsible for directing to the template.  unless of course there's a way in a view to direct to the url of another view in such a way that the url in the browser window changes which solves the problem.

Comment: I hate to bring you bad news, but you really should try the django tutorial.  It will show you how to structure your app (including url confs, and forms, and redirections).  Part 3 will show you how to use urlconfs with variables in them.  Then you will be able to redirect to a page and specify a particular model.  Part 4 shows you forms, you'll also want to learn about forms and form validation (you have no forms above, you need some).  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/  Maybe the forms tutorial can also help you with logging in the user, as that is another form.

Comment: I did do the tutorial before I started this project and I don't see anything in there about forms, do you mean views?  That's what Tutorial 3 (which you linked to) discusses which I am using.

Comment: My main confusion with what they supply in the tutorial is that I don't understand how I can return a HTML page that prompts the user to input and then operate on that data.  If I've returned the page then the method has ended and the next logical place for the program to go is back to the index page which is what I'm doing now but the tutorial doesn't do that and it is very confusing to me.